How to draw a sphere that is tangent to the three coordinate planes?
I am trying to draw a sphere that is tangent to the three coordinate planes. I tried
Graphics3D[{Cyan, Sphere[{5, 5, 5}, 5]}, Boxed -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 12}, {0, 12}, {0, 12}}, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral", 
 FaceGrids -> 
  Table[{face, {Range[0, 12, 1], 
     Range[0, 12, 1]}}, {face, -IdentityMatrix[3]}], 
 PlotRangePadding -> 0]


Graphics3D[{{Red, Opacity[0.3], 
   InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}, {0, 10, 0}}]},{Green, Opacity[0.3], 
   InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}]},{Blue, Opacity[0.3], 
   InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 10, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}]},Blue, Sphere[{5, 5, 5}, 5] }, Boxed -> False,
  PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}, ViewPoint -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]


How can I  get like this?


Do you mean to, like, change the ViewPoint?

Maybe this: Rotate it around how you would like it. Select the output cell. Do the menu command Cell > Show Expression. Copy the ViewPoint and ViewVertical settings and paste the options into the original Graphics3D code.

@MichaelE2 I have just edited.

I don't see much difference, in terms of pure planes and sphere, except that the sphere does not look tangent to the left wall. I assume you're not asking for the shadow and textures on the wall, floor, and ball, since these were not mentioned in the orignal post.

Do you mean like this?: https://i.sstatic.net/Z4ZsXyEm.png

Yes. Thank you very much.

It may take some practice to get the hang of manipulating the 3d graphics, but I put a link to the documentation. Right-click on the graphics allows you to reset the pan/zoom.

A sphere in the first quadrant that is tangent to the coordinates planes lies on the diagonal: {x,x,x} and has radius: x.

@DanielHuber Thank you very much.

By rotating, panning and zooming; and then examining the cell expression:
Graphics3D[{{Red, Opacity[0.3], 
   InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}, {0, 10, 0}}]}, {Green, 
   Opacity[0.3], 
   InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {10, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}]}, {Blue, 
   Opacity[0.3], InfinitePlane[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 10, 0}, {0, 0, 10}}]}, 
  Blue, Sphere[{5, 8, 5}, 5]}, BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
    Boxed -> False, 
    Lighting -> "Neutral", PlotRange -> 
      {{0, 16}, {0, 20}, {0, 16}}, ViewAngle -> 
      0.3650542014175573, ViewCenter -> 
      {{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {0.5497749751920034, 
          0.6460255657375193}}, ViewPoint -> 
      {1.3937013088594503, 0.937665108360899, 
        0.42235151976286206}, ViewVertical -> 
      {0.3018032845666661, 0.1620511984890498, 
        0.9394967730083135}]



Note I made the plot range a bit bigger, so that the zoom in would occupy the image rectangle.

I don't understand when you used Sphere[{5, 8, 5}, 5]

@JohnPaulPeter Change the center to {5, 5, 5} as you had originally. I mentioned in a comment that it didn't appear to me that the ball was tangent to the left wall. It's a bit hard to tell, though, from just one perspective. That is what I showed. I figured whatever I showed, you would want to manipulate the graphics to your liking anyway. The key here, besides manipulating the graphics, is to use Show Expression to copy the option setting of the four View* options. You might change ViewVertical to Vertical -> {0,0,1} and see if you like that better.
